# Play2 Web Framework "play start" is different from "play run"

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0

I created a new Play 2.1.2 web application using "play new test". When I start it using "play run" I see the default "Your new application is ready" screen nicely formated. But when I start it using "play start", all the formating (assets?) is missing. I only see the text "Your new application is ready".

These files are missing:
- main.css
- widget?uid=xxxxxxxxx
- header-pattern.png
- external.png, widget?uid=xxxxxxxx
- news.png
- __utm.gif?yyyyyyyy

What do I have to do to make the production mode work properly?

Comment: Are you aware of this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291374/whats-the-difference-between-using-play-start-and-play-run?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple scala playframework app doesn't work on heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311308/simple-scala-playframework-app-doesnt-work-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start... coding your own code, initially the index view contains only the call to the local documentation : `@play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")` and as James Ward wrote it is not accessible from production mode.

As soon as you'll add own styles and content you'll realize that everything works like a charm in both modes. Compare to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13311829/1066240) which is actually identical to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Running Play in prod mode with `play start` turns off the documentation.  There is no way to run Play in prod mode and still have the documentation accessible.